# Broken quest (Leifnarr's death). Is it possible to fix it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

as per subject I'm on PS3 and unfortunately I've uncovered the body of Leifnarr before getting the quest.

Is it possible to *get* the quest after you've found the body?

I've read around on PC you can re-trigger the quest... Is it there the *console* on PS3? I could connect a USB keyboard in case and try reset it.

Comment: Well, the console may actually be there via a USB keyboard, try it and see (I know oblivion on the xbox360 had the console, but one needed to plug in a USB keyboard to access it). Just be warned, if a command is run they may decide you are trying to cheat at achievements/trophies and not give you any more on that characer (at least fallout 3 and fallout new vegas were supposed to do this on PC's)

Comment: @ewanm89 No, it's not there at all on consoles. Also, using the console doesn't prevent achievements on PC.

Comment: It was on oblivion, I said I didn't know about the rest, and to try it, and I said it was supposed to in related engine games on the PC, but it didn't always work that functionality either.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no console on the PS3 even with a USB keyboard.

There is no known way to complete this quest on a console if the correct dialogue isn't available on his

> wife Grosta or son at Heartwood Mill

However, if you just want to clear the quest from your journal, you can

> kill his wife Grosta

That's [confirmed to work on the PS3](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Leifnarr).

Comment: I found his body and now it's telling me to find his family.  Where is Grosta located?

Comment: Check the first spoiler text. It's on the western edge of the lake Riften is on.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, don't find his body before speaking to his quest giver. If you come across his body, immediately reload a prior save and do not click on him. Instead, travel to his quest giver (in the above spoilers) and then go back and click on him. If you click him first, the quest will never complete and will stay in your list.

Answer (score -3):

If you get stuck with the quest in your list and can't get the dialogue to pop with his wife, just kill her & the quest goes away. I swear this works.